# My macbookair tried to drink my coffee and now, everything is upside-down

Tags: keyboard, trackpad

A few days ago, some coffee went on my MBA(4,2).

I immediately took it down, unplugged it from the magsafe, and started to open it to dry it the faster I was able to.

After a few days in rice and putting the piece back together I booted it. It was working *quite* well given what happened **but** now the fan are going full speed, even after SMC & NVRAM reset. The SMC Fan Controller can see the speed of the fan (6500rpm) and I can't change it. Which is annoying.

But what is ***way more*** annoying is that now my trackpad & keyboard are dead. Well, almost dead. Because I can still boot my mac. **By the way, the keyboard backlight is still working as usual, enabled when a key is pressed (just the power key) and disabled after 10 secs)**

How can I fix theses two issues (preferably with a lot of time and the less money as possible)?

(ps: I didn't find better tags, please, feel free to fix this :) )

Comment: Was it regular or decaf, with or w/out cream and or sugar and how much was spilt? Did you do anything other then trying to absorb the liquid, like using special cleaners designed for pc boards and sensitive electronics?

Comment: @user3439894 black regular. This is a kind of rule to me. If rice and tissues count as special stuff, yes.

Comment: Regular black coffee by itself can leave a residue so tissues and rice are not necessarily enough to clean up a spill and no those are not special cleaners to which I refer.  There are aerosolized highly evaporative residueless nonconductive cleaners designed for pc boards and sensitive electronics. I haven't had the need to use them in over 10 years  so I don't have the product names handy.  I purchased these spray cleaners at an electronics warehouse and used them on PC's where the pc boards would get covered with tar and nicotine and overheat and had to be cleaned in order to continue use.

Answer (score 1):

For the fan, you need to differentiate between a fan problem or temperature problem. You need to see if the laptop is over heating when running the fan at full speed. Use something like TG Pro.

For trackpad and keyboard, you need to be able to see input live, so that you can tell if the trackpad/keyboard is in fact dead or working randomly. BetterTouchTool gives a live view of the trackpad. Karabiner does the similar thing for keyboard.

Comment: I checked the temp, which is around 40°C (nothing high). I'll check for BTT asap

Comment: 40 Celsius @ max speed is not low either.

Comment: My mbp is 50°C at max speed when in idle :)

Comment: 2011 13' MBP 44 Degree average / 55 CPU @ 2000 rpm as I type this in Firefox.

Comment: Well I guess this is the minimum temp reachable :p